# MAUI How to set the TopBar background color?

Tags: maui, .net-maui.shell, maui-shell

**How can I change / set the color of the top bar?**

(for all pages at my app)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Shell

Since you're using [Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/pages#set-page-colors), this should be done using `Shell.BackgroundColor`:

```xml
<ContentPage
    x:Class="MauiSamples.Views.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    Shell.BackgroundColor="DarkGreen">

    <!-- content goes here -->

</ContentPage>
```

You can also see how that works in my samples repository: https://github.com/ewerspej/maui-samples.

If you want to have the same style per page, then you can also change this in the *Styles.xaml* or define your own style somewhere in a similar fashion:

```xml
<Style TargetType="Shell" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
    <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="DarkGreen" />
    
    <!-- skipping other styles -->

</Style>
```

Another way would be to set the `TitleView` to a Layout that fills the available space and give that a `BackgroundColor`:

```xml
<ContentPage
    x:Class="MauiSamples.Views.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">

    <Shell.TitleView>
        <Grid
            VerticalOptions="Fill"
            HorizontalOptions="Fill"
            BackgroundColor="DarkGreen">
            
        </Grid>
    </Shell.TitleView>

    <!-- content goes here -->

</ContentPage>
```

## NavigationPage

When a [NavigationPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/navigationpage) is used instead of Shell, then it should be `BarBackgroundColor`, e.g.:

```cs
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MyContentPage())
{
    BarBackgroundColor = Colors.DarkGreen
};
```

This should be similar for *TabbedPage*.

Comment: I've just crreated a new MAUI project in VisualStudio 2022 and it doesn't have any of these.

Comment: @RichardBarraclough Not sure what you mean. It doesn't have any of what?

Comment: I don't have a `Shell.BackgroundColor` or a `Shell.TitleView`. I can't find out where this purple is coming from.

Comment: TBH, that's not sufficient information to help you. I don't know what exactly you're doing or trying to accomplish (e.g. what do you mean by "where this purple is coming from"?). Maybe write your own question, if you don't manage to figure out what it is you're trying to do.